# Proving an implication by disproving its converse

Tags: logic

Can we prove an ‘if’ statement by proving that its converse is false? That is, is $$\lnot (B \implies A); \text{ therefore, } (A \implies B)$$ a sound argument? Speaking to several colleagues about this has not convinced me of this. The sentence $$\lnot (B \rightarrow A) \to (A \rightarrow B)$$ is certainly valid, as can be seen from its truth table. However, its antecedent implies $\lnot A$ which feels like it should violate soundness.

Comment: A statement and its converse may both be false.

Comment: Proving the converse is false DOES NOT IMPLY that the statement is true. However, if the contrapositive statement is true then the statement itself is necessarily true

Comment: @QuiGonnJinn The latter is of course correct. However, the former is up for debate.

Comment: You said that you're not convinced with this proof, which proof are you talking about?

Comment: Updated to elaborate

Comment: Are you sure @KaviRamaMurthy ? That's news to me.

Comment: There are two cases: if $A^c$ is countable, then "if $A$ is countable then $A^c$ is countable" holds trivially. Otherwise, $A^c$ is not countable, and so "if $A^c$ is countable then $A$ is countable" holds vacuously. In any case, they're not both false.

Comment: @Z.A.K. What I meant was the statement: If  a subset of $\mathbb R$ is countable then so it its comlement. I don't want to fix a set $A$.

Comment: $A\implies B$ means $(\neg A)\lor B$.

Comment: Start with the premise: $\lnot (B \to A)$ and then assume $A$. From it we have $B \to A$ and thus a contradiction, from which $B$ follows. Now conclude to $A \to B$, discharging the assumption $A$. The result is: $\lnot (B \to A) \vdash (A \to B)$

Comment: Is this meant to be _predicate_ logic, or _propositional_ logic?

Comment: The negation of the converse is true only when $B$ Is true and $A$ is false. This is just one of three truth valuations for $A, B$ that make the implication true. It does imply the implication. However, the implication does *not* imply the negation of the converse. Perhaps you’re thinking of this: $A\Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"However,the antecedent implies ¬A which feels like it should violate soundness."

The antecedent (the implication $\lnot$(B$\rightarrow$A)) implying $\lnot$A, on the contrary, *further enforces* soundness.  Soundness means that if the premises are all true, than the conclusion will hold true.  Validity means that it's impossible for the premises to hold true and the conclusion to be false.  Basically any implication which is always true will also imply validity for associated rules of inference and enforces soundness when the axioms are tautologies.  This works this way, because of the meta-theorem: From ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$) we can infer $\alpha$$\vdash$$\beta$, which allows us to get rules of inference from tautologies quickly.  So, it suffices to demonstrate that the implication is a tautology for associated rules of inference to work out as valid and will help to enforce soundness.

Since truth tables haven't sufficed, I'll appeal to two logical laws below directly, after analyzing what follows from the denial of an implication.

If we have $\lnot$(B$\rightarrow$A), then two propositions immediately follow: the antecedent is true and the consequent is false.  So, we have B here.  We also have $\lnot$A here.

There accordingly exist two relevant logical laws for showing that (A$\rightarrow$B) follows from this.  ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$($\beta$$\rightarrow$$\alpha$)) and ($\lnot$$\alpha$$\rightarrow$($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$)).

Proof 1:  Given $\lnot$(B$\rightarrow$A), we have $\lnot$A.  So, since ($\lnot$$\alpha$$\rightarrow$($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$)) is a logical law, (A$\rightarrow$B) follows by one application of modus ponens. Therefore, invoking conditional introduction also, ($\lnot$(B$\rightarrow$A)$\rightarrow$(A$\rightarrow$B)).

Proof 2: Given $\lnot$(B$\rightarrow$A), we have B.  So, since ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$($\beta$$\rightarrow$$\alpha$)) is a logical law, (A$\rightarrow$B) follows.  Therefore, invoking conditional introduction also, ($\lnot$(B$\rightarrow$A)$\rightarrow$(A$\rightarrow$B)).

Comment: Hey Doug thank you this seems like the most helpful answer here. Why does this method not work in practice? Is it universal quantifiers as @DanielV has mentioned?

Comment: @Lev The issue is equivocating "the implication $A \to B$ is false" with $\lnot (A \to B)$.  Almost always (exactly when there are free variables) "the implication $A \to B$ is false" should properly be written $\lnot \forall x . Ax \to Bx$ (with x representing the free variables), and that CANNOT be proven by establishing $\forall x. Bx \to Ax$.  The case where your technique works is limited to when you actually mean $\lnot (A \to B)$, which is quite rare.

Comment: @DanielV If ¬(A→B), then A.  If ¬(A→B), then $\lnot$B.  You can check that both (¬(A→B)$\rightarrow$A) and (¬(A→B)$\rightarrow$$\lnot$B) are tautologies.  If we have A and $\lnot$B, then the implication (A$\rightarrow$B) is false.  Thus, the implication (A$\rightarrow$B) as false follows from ¬(A→B).  If (A$\rightarrow$B) is false, then $\lnot$(A$\rightarrow$B) is true.  So, from (A$\rightarrow$B) as false, $\lnot$(A$\rightarrow$B) follows.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood That you think you need to say that to me suggests you never actually read anything I wrote on this.

Answer (score 5):

> Can we prove an ‘if’ statement by proving that its converse is false?

**Proving an implication by disproving its converse is legitimate only if said implication is not quantified.**

1. Logically, the non-quantified statement $$\text{Amy being a vegan implies that she eats beef}$$ and its converse $$\text{Amy eating beef implies that she is a vegan}$$ cannot both be false: if one is false, then the other must be vacuously true.
2. However, the quantified statement $$\text{Every vegan eats beef}$$ and its converse $$\text{Every beef-eater is a vegan}$$ ***are both false***.

### Explanation

The open formula $A(x)\rightarrow B(x)$ often implicitly means the sentence $\forall x\,\Big(A(x)\rightarrow B(x)\Big),$ which is different from the sentence $A \rightarrow B.$

1. The sentence $$\lnot (B \rightarrow A) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow
      B)$$ is a tautology. Thus, $$\text{not }\Big(B\to A\Big)$$
   logically entails $$A \to B.$$
2. On the other hand, the sentence $$\lnot\forall x\,\Big(B(x)\rightarrow
      A(x)\Big)\,\rightarrow\,\forall x\,\Big(A(x)\rightarrow B(x)\Big)$$ is
   (satisfiable but) *invalid*. Thus, $$\text{not }\forall x\,
      \Big(B(x)\to A(x)\Big)$$ **does not logically
   entail** $$\forall x\,\Big(A(x)\to B(x)\Big).$$

---

> Can we prove an ‘if’ statement by proving that its converse is false?
> That is, is $$\lnot (B \implies A); \text{ therefore, } (A \implies B)$$ a sound argument?   It is certainly valid.  However, $\lnot (B \rightarrow A)$ implies $\lnot A$ which feels like it should violate soundness.

To be clear: your suggested proof/argument's premise $\lnot (B \rightarrow A)$ *is* satisfiable, regardless of the fact that it is consistent with your target implication $(A\to B)$'s hypothesis $A$ being false. On the other hand, if you reframe your proof as having premise $\big(\lnot (B \rightarrow A)\;\land\;A\big)$ and conclusion $B,$ then this premise is *still* consistent with your observation that $\lnot (B \rightarrow A)\to\lnot A$ is a tautology. In both cases, your suggested argument *isn't* categorically unsound. It is unsound precisely when $A$ is true and $B$ false, in which case your target implication (is false and) cannnot be proven.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on if there is an implicit quantifier or not.  For example:

$x \text { is even } \to x \text{ is odd}$

Both that and the converse is false.  So using the falseness of one to prove the truth of the other would be a fallacy. However, because there is an implicit $\forall x$ in front of it, it is language sensitive whether you want to say it even has a converse.

On the other hand, if you look at the truth table of implication:

$$\begin{array} {cc|c}
A & B & A \to B \\
\text{T} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\
\text{T} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\
\text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\
\text{F} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\
\end{array}$$

You can see that the only way for a statement $A\to B$ to be false is for $A=\text{T}$ and $B=\text{F}$, which determines that $B\to A$ is in fact true.  But this only works if there are no free variables, which is to say: no implicit quantifiers.

So you could correctly use the falseness of

$$1=1 \to 2=3$$

to prove

$$2=3 \to 1=1$$

But you'll find there are very few statements like that in mathematics without free variables, which is implicit quantification.  And that type of statement is vacuous anyway which also makes it less likely to come up.

Comment: "Both that and the converse is false." No. If "x is even →x is odd" is false, then the antecedent is true and the consequent is false. So, x is even, and x is not odd. Since x is even, "x is odd implies x is even" is true. Since x is not odd, "x is odd implies x is even" is true. So, doubly so, the converse is true.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I think you're missing the part where there is an implicit $\forall x$, as in $\forall x . x \text{ is even} \to x \text{ is odd}$ is false, but also $\forall x$, as in $\forall x . x \text{ is odd} \to x \text{ is even}$ is also false.

Comment: That doesn't have the form ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$).  The assertion that for all x, x is even IS false, and thus the conditional "for all x, x is even implies x is odd" is true, because the antecedent "for all x, x is even" is false.  The same holds for the conditional "for all x, x is odd implies x is even".  Also, both conditionals "for all x (x is even implies x is odd)" and "for all x (x is odd implies x is even)" are true, because the assertions "x is odd" and "x is even" are both false, since oddness and evenness only applies to constants, not to any variables over the naturals.

Comment: Also, were it the case that all natural numbers were even, then all natural numbers would also be odd.  And also, if all natural numbers were even, all of them would also be odd.  One theorem of the division of the natural numbers into the odds and the evens is that such a partition exhausts all natural numbers.  Thus, as a consequence if all natural numbers had one of those properties, they would have to have the other one.  In which case both conditionals would hold true.

Comment: "Also, both conditionals "for all x (x is even implies x is odd)" and "for all x (x is odd implies x is even)" are true, because the assertions "x is odd" and "x is even" are both false, since oddness and evenness only applies to constants, not to any variables over the naturals. "  That is so wrong I don't even know where to begin correcting you.  What I said is correct.  And presuming to interpret $\forall x. Px \to Qx$ as $(\forall x . Px)$ is not an honest interpretation of what I wrote.

Comment: A number can be even or odd.  Variables can't.  Numbers are constants, not variables.  Thus, oddness and evenness only applies to constants, not any variables over the naturals.  It isn't clear from the notation whatsoever whether ∀x.Px→Qx means ((∀xPx)→Qx) or ∀x(Px→Qx), since if we assume some sort of right parenthesis it can happen in more than one place.  Again, it's not correct to say that "x is even →x is odd" is false when x is any possible natural number.  The antecedent is false, and thus the implication is true.  "x is odd  → x is even" is similarly a true implication.