# Can an implication and its converse both be false?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Is the statement “Every implication or its converse must be true” correct, or is it possible to have both implication and converse be false?

If $A$ stands for "$x$ is a prime number" and $B$ stands for "$x$ is greater than $100$", then both $(A → B)$ and $(B → A)$ are false. Is this a counterexample to the quoted statement? How does this make sense with respect to the truth table of $(A → B) ∨ (B → A)$ showing that it is always true?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Because "$x$ is a prime number" is not an absolute statement until you tell me what $x$ is.  Basically, your statement has a quantifier in it.

Comment: Note that your example is implicitly quantified, which changes how it would be analyzed in this context. 

Either way, $(A \to B) \lor (B \to A)$ is a Classical tautology as you mention, and even Intuitionistic Logic can’t have both an implication and its converse as false. However, an implication and its converse can both fail to be *true* in Intuitionistic Logic. 

There are weaker logics where both an implication and its converse can be false.

Comment: @CrSb0001 that’s clearly false. The post is more than intelligible and asks a specific question.

Comment: Related: [Proving an implication by disproving its converse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4222929/21813)

Answer (score 7):

Put $Px$ for $x$ is prime, and $Gx$ for $x > 100$.

Now distinguish

1. $\forall x(Px \to Gx) \lor \forall x(Gx \to Px)$

from

2. $\forall x((Px \to Gx) \lor (Gx \to Px))$

The first I think properly captures the thought that you say is false (for yes, the generalization $\forall x(Px \to Gx)$ is false, and likewise $\forall x(Gx \to Px)$ is false). But (1) is not a logical theorem.

On the other had (2) is a classical theorem, but is *not* obviously false, once distinguished from (1). Take any $n$ you like. Then either $Pn$ is false, in which case the supposition that $Pn$ is true leads to contradiction, and anything goes, so we get in particular $(Pn \to Gn)$. Or $Pn$ is true, in which case $(Gn \to Pn)$. So either way we get $((Pn \to Gn) \lor (Gn \to Pn))$. But $n$ was arbitrary so we can generalize.

Comment: Is $\forall x(Px \to Gx),$ *strictly speaking*, not the converse of $\forall x(Gx \to Px)$? ([Many sites](https://storm.cis.fordham.edu/zhang/cs2100/slides/PredicateLogic.pdf) consider them the converse of each other.)

Comment: I would say that it could be/is  misleading to use "converse" in a way that makes those two converses.